# How to determine a video file's framerate with MediaCodec, MediaExtractor or MediaMetadataRetriever?

Tags: android, video, media, android-mediacodec, mediaextractor

How to I extract the frame rate of a recorded video file? I know that there is MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE and that I can access MediaFormat objects through MediaExtractor. However KEY_FRAME_RATE is only available for encoders. Instead I want to find out the frame rate of an already recorded video.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there is no way to get framerate through any of official API functions. It might require some extra logic - count times between timestamps or to parse headers info. in general h.264 standard allows variable framerate, so frame times could differ from one to one. for example if can show some static picture for several seconds or so

Comment: A simple example of VFR is the videos generated by the "screenrecord" command in kitkat.  If the video isn't recorded at a constant frame rate, there's no way to know the number of frames (other than counting them), and there's no such thing as The Frame Rate.  You could compute a peak frame rate, which might be what the OP is after.

Comment: is there a requirement for hw encoders on android devices to work in vfr mode and is there a test\plan to have tests to check that?

Comment: I don't know.  And I don't work there anymore, so it'd be difficult to find out. :-)

Comment: i see:) *offtopic* are you going to support and expand grafika and bigflake in future? these resources are really great

Comment: I have no immediate plans to do so.  My hope is that the graphics team will continue to enhance Grafika, and bigflake.com will be replaced by "official" sample code from the media team.

Comment: @fadden, the reason, why I asked this question was because I need to do some video editing based on timing information. So I record some editing information during video playback and store it together with timestamps I get from the media player (getDuration()). Afterwards, I want to create a video, where I apply the edit script based on the timing info. It seems that getTimestamp() of SurfaceTexture in onFrameAvailable() does not match getDuration() so I tried to use frame counting by computing the frame time based on the frame rate of the input video.

Comment: Video file time stamps don't necessarily start at zero.  If you subtract the timestamp of the last frame from the timestamp of the first frame, you should know the exact duration of the video, not including the last frame.  (By the last part I mean if the first frame is at time 100, and the second at time 300, the video duration is not 300-100=200, because that doesn't take into account the time to show the final frame.)

Comment: @fadden, thank you for the explanation. This is what I already tried and I think I am experiencing exactly the issue that the display time is not taken into account. What I do: I check the frame time of the first frame and sore it as offset, then I subtract this one for each following frame. After the last frame, the progress is not 100% but only 96% because the display time is not taken into account. So if i render with 30fps, the display time is 33ms for each frame. If I add this to each frame, the progress count in the end is weigh beyond 100%. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

When using `MediaExtractor`, if your video track has a stable FPS, then you know for sure your `MediaExtractor` is advancing by the frame duration you are searching for.

Before doing anything, just after having set up your `MediaExtractor`, you can do the following:

```
mediaExtractor.Advance();
var fps = 1000000f / (float) mediaExtractor.SampleTime;
mediaExtractor.SeekTo(0, MediaExtractorSeekTo.None);
```

Like I said, you can't take for grant that all your frames have the same duration. Frame presentation time are totally arbitrary, but I feel it's not common to not have a stable FPS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ffmpeg to get the frame rate of a video (https://www.ffmpeg.org) - subject to the comments that fadden and Marlon make on variable frames rates in the comments to the accepted answer.

There are a number of ways to include ffmpeg in Android - the one I found the best compromise between complexity and functionality was to wrap the command line ffmpeg program in a Java JNI wrapper.

There are a couple of issues to look out for, including an issue with invoking ffmpeg twice via the wrapper, so it is worth either using or studying existing Android wrapper solutions - e.g.:

- http://writingminds.github.io/ffmpeg-android-java/

From the documentation there:

```js
FFmpeg ffmpeg = FFmpeg.getInstance(context);
try {
  // to execute "ffmpeg -version" command you just need to pass "-version"
  ffmpeg.execute(cmd, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onProgress(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFailure(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {}

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {}
  });
} catch (FFmpegCommandAlreadyRunningException e) {
  // Handle if FFmpeg is already running
}
```

An example of ffmpeg cmd to get the frame rate, replacing filename with the name of the file you want to check:

```js
cmd = "-i filename";
```

Your code can then parse the output for the fps - see example output below:

```html
ffmpeg version 2.6.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with llvm-gcc 4.2.1 (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
  configuration: --prefix=/Volumes/Ramdisk/sw --enable-gpl --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-libspeex --enable-libvpx --disable-decoder=libvpx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-avfilter --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-filters --enable-libgsm --enable-libvidstab --enable-libx265 --disable-doc --arch=x86_64 --enable-runtime-cpudetect
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/BBB/Desktop/vid_bigbuckbunny.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: mp42avc1
    creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
  Duration: 00:01:00.10, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 733 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 22050 Hz, stereo, fltp, 65 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : Apple Sound Media Handler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 640x360, 612 kb/s, 23.96 fps, 24 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : Apple Video Media Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 45 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : hint media handler
    Stream #0:3(eng): Data: none (rtp  / 0x20707472), 5 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-02-09 01:55:39
      handler_name    : hint media handler
```

Bear in mind that ffmpeg syntax and output format can change over time, so for the parsing in particular you need to allow for this, although looking for 'fps' in the output will probably generally work anyway.

Also be aware that many video 'containers' (e.g. mp4, often referred to as the video file) may contain multiple video streams and the different streams may have different frame rates. This will be included in the output from ffmpeg so something else to check for when parsing the output.

And finally, just a reminder again that the frame rate may not be constant for a video so use with this in mind.

Comment: You are right, but including FFMPEG only for calculating the frame rate is a huge overhead I think

Comment: Form a complexity and effort point of view, the overhead is significant, definitely - no arguments there. For speed, app size etc it may not be such an issue.

Comment: Last link - 404, and it would be great if you could show a snippet to get FPS with FFMPEG

Comment: Great! Yesterday parsed FPS from this output by "kb/s," )))